# Why is my python Mario program less comfortable ignoring the spaces?

Tags: python, cs50

I'm working on cs50 pset6 python Mario, and it's supposed to take an int as input (the int is named height) and then make a mario pyramid of size(height), like this:

```
$ python mario.py
Height: 4
   #
  ##
 ###
####
```

But my program prints this:

```
~/ $ python mario.py
Height: 4
#
##
###
####
```

I don't know why. Here's my code:

```py
from cs50 import get_int

height = get_int("Height: ")
while height < 1 or height > 8:
height = get_int("Height:")

for i in range(1, height+1):
    for j in range(height - i):
        print("", end = '')
    if i == 1:
        print("#")
    if i == 2:
        print("##")
    if i == 3:
        print("###")
    if i == 4:
        print("####")
    if i == 5:
        print("#####")
    if i == 6:
        print("######")
    if i == 7:
        print("#######")
    if i == 8:
        print("########")
```

If you find my bug, please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: You need to put spaces in front of the '#'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are printing an empty string instead of white spaces:

```
print("", end = '')
```

Try this instead:

```
print(" ", end = '')
```

Comment: Thanks, it's that I'm new to python and thought it automatically prints spaces when there's nothing in the string.

Comment: Glad it helped you. Feel free to accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Yeah I'm about to but it says I can only do it in two minutes ;)